Как сделать SVG из длины стороны и угла

Получил вот такое тз. Не знаю как учитывать угол при составлении svg. С геометрией у меня не очень. Помогите пожалуйста
Нашел во такую функцию,
function findNewPoint(x, y, angle, distance) {
    var result = {};

    result.x = Math.round(Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + x);
    result.y = Math.round(Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance + y);

    return result;
}

var newPoint = findNewPoint(724, 97, 90, 1300);
console.log('newPoint:', newPoint);

но она не учитывает предыдущий угол.

Начните с рисунка на бумаге, не подсматривая на картинку из ТЗ, а только на цифры из таблички.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В таблице неверно указаны данные, в svg любая координата имеет две точки в вашем случае одна...
